# error in wrapping class for dll functions

Tags: c++, dll, scope, stack, activation

I have a 3rd party .dll (and relative .h and .lib) to control a device via USB.

I want to use the dll functions into a class (AOTF_controller) to implement my desired behaviour.
What I want to do is :

1. Connect to the device (connect() class function);
2. Initialize it (init() class function);
3. Set some parameters (setScanningFreq() class function)
4. Increase sequentially the frequency of my device (increaseFreq() class function)
5. Reset and close the USB connection.

I can obtain this behavior when I use the dll functions directly into the _tmain() therefore the device works correctly, but when I wrap the dll functions into a class and try to use the class something goes wrong.
I repeat the above process (list item 1-5) several times: sometimes it works fine, sometimes the program stop and the debugger gives me this error:

First-chance exception at 0x77533fb7 in AOTFcontrollerDebug.exe: 0xC0150014: The activation context activation stack for the running thread of execution is corrupt.

The error seems random, sometimes I can conclude 80 times the scan without any problem, sometimes it gives me error right at the first scan.
I tried to search for that error but I was not able to find anything useful.

Anyone can help? I guess could be related on how the dll functions are called in my class?

Here is the main function code:

```
// AOTFcontrollerDebug.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "AOTFcontrollerDebug.h"
#include "AOTF_Controller.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <AotfLibrary.h>

#define DEFAULT_STARTFREQUENCY 78
#define DEFAULT_ENDFREQUENCY 95.5
#define DEFAULT_NUMOFFRAMES 256

#ifdef _DEBUG
#define new DEBUG_NEW
#endif

// The one and only application object

CWinApp theApp;

using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, TCHAR* argv[], TCHAR* envp[])
{
    int nRetCode = 0;

    HMODULE hModule = ::GetModuleHandle(NULL);

    if (hModule != NULL)
    {
        // initialize MFC and print and error on failure
        if (!AfxWinInit(hModule, NULL, ::GetCommandLine(), 0))
        {
            // TODO: change error code to suit your needs
            _tprintf(_T("Fatal Error: MFC initialization failed\n"));
            nRetCode = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            // TODO: code your application's behavior here.
            std::cout << "-----AOTF Controller Debugging-----"<<endl;

            //input of scans to do
            int repeatedScan;
            std::cout << "Type how many repeated scan: "<<endl;
            std::cin >> repeatedScan;

            //instance  
            AOTF_Controller m_AOTF_Controller;
            std::cout << "AOTF Controller instance done..."<<endl;

            //loop over scans
            for(int i =0;i<repeatedScan;i++)
            {
                m_AOTF_Controller.connect();
                std::cout << "AOTF Controller connected..."<<endl;
                std::cout << "Scan number : "<< (i + 1) <<endl;

                m_AOTF_Controller.init();
                //set the delta freq to increase at each step
                m_AOTF_Controller.setScanningFreq(DEFAULT_STARTFREQUENCY, DEFAULT_ENDFREQUENCY, DEFAULT_NUMOFFRAMES);

                //loop over wavelengths
                int sleep_ms = 4;
                for (int j =0; j <DEFAULT_NUMOFFRAMES; j++)
                {
                    Sleep(sleep_ms) ;
                    m_AOTF_Controller.increaseFreq();
                    //std::cout << " "<< (j + 1) ;
                }

                // terminate scans
                m_AOTF_Controller.reset();
                m_AOTF_Controller.disconnect();
                std::cout << endl <<"Scan number "<< (i + 1) << "terminated successfully" <<endl;

                Sleep(sleep_ms*100) ;
            }
        }       
    }
    else
    {
        // TODO: change error code to suit your needs
        _tprintf(_T("Fatal Error: GetModuleHandle failed\n"));
        nRetCode = 1;
    }

    return nRetCode;
}
```

and here the Aotf_Controller class code:

```
//Aotf_Controller.h
#pragma once

#include <AotfLibrary.h>
#include <string> 
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>

#define CONVERSION_MHZ_TO_HZ 1000000

class AOTF_Controller
{
private:
enum Error {SUCCESSFUL , CONNECTION_ERROR, DISCONNECTION_ERROR, INIT_ERROR, RESET_ERROR ,    SET_ERROR }; // error enum values

HANDLE  hAotfController;
int currentGain;
long currentFreq; // current frequency in Hz
long startFreq, endFreq, deltaFreq; // frequency values for the scanning in Hz

public:
    AOTF_Controller(void);
    ~AOTF_Controller(void);
    AOTF_Controller::Error connect();
    AOTF_Controller::Error disconnect();
    AOTF_Controller::Error init();
    AOTF_Controller::Error setFreq(float freq); // for frequency value in MHZ (precision to the 3rd decimal i.e. KHz)
    AOTF_Controller::Error setFreq(long freq); // for frequency value in Hz 
    AOTF_Controller::Error setGain(int gain);
    AOTF_Controller::Error reset();
    AOTF_Controller::Error setScanningFreq(float _startFreq, float _endFreq, int numOfFrames);
    AOTF_Controller::Error increaseFreq();
    };

//Aotf_Controller.cpp

#include "StdAfx.h"
#include "AOTF_Controller.h"

AOTF_Controller::AOTF_Controller(void)
{
    currentGain = 0;
    currentFreq = 0; 
    startFreq = 0;
    endFreq = 0;
    deltaFreq = 0;
    hAotfController = NULL;
}

AOTF_Controller::~AOTF_Controller(void)
{
}

AOTF_Controller::Error AOTF_Controller::connect()
{
    int iInstance = 0;
    hAotfController = AotfOpen(iInstance);

    if (!hAotfController)
    {
        return CONNECTION_ERROR;
    }
    else
    {
        return SUCCESSFUL;
    }
}

AOTF_Controller::Error AOTF_Controller::disconnect()
{
    if (!AotfClose (hAotfController))
    {
        return DISCONNECTION_ERROR;
    }
    else
    {
        hAotfController = NULL;
        return SUCCESSFUL;
    }
}

AOTF_Controller::Error AOTF_Controller::init()
{
    std::string ampCom="dds a 0 16383\r"; //Command to set the amplitude parameter to the max
    std::string modCom="mod dac * 16383\r";//Command to set the dac parameter to the max
    int gain = 255; // set the gain to the max

    if (!AotfWrite(hAotfController, ampCom.length(), (char *)ampCom.c_str()))
    {
        return Error::INIT_ERROR;
    }

    if (!AotfWrite(hAotfController, modCom.length(), (char *)modCom.c_str()))
    {
        return INIT_ERROR;
    }

    setGain(gain);

    return SUCCESSFUL;
}

AOTF_Controller::Error AOTF_Controller::reset()
{
    std::string resetCom = "dds reset\r";

    if(!AotfWrite(hAotfController, resetCom.length() , (char *)resetCom.c_str())) 
    {
        return RESET_ERROR;
    } 
    return SUCCESSFUL;
}

AOTF_Controller::Error AOTF_Controller::setFreq(float freq)
{
    long freqHz = (long)freq*CONVERSION_MHZ_TO_HZ;
    setFreq(freqHz);
    return SUCCESSFUL;
}

AOTF_Controller::Error AOTF_Controller::setFreq(long freq)
{
    std::ostringstream oss; //stream to build the string

    //building the string for the Frequency 
    oss << "dds f 0 !" << std::fixed << std::setprecision(0) << freq << "\r";
    std::string freqCom = oss.str();

    //send command to the AOTF
    if(!AotfWrite(hAotfController, freqCom.length(), (char *) freqCom.c_str())) // set the frequency (80-120)
    {
        return SET_ERROR;
    } 

    currentFreq = freq; // update monitoring variable in HZ

    return Error::SUCCESSFUL;
}

AOTF_Controller::Error AOTF_Controller::setGain(int gain)
{
    std::ostringstream oss; //stream to build the string

    //building the string for the Gain
    oss << "dds gain -p* * " << gain << "\r";
    std::string gainCom = oss.str();

    //send command to the AOTF
    if(!AotfWrite(hAotfController, gainCom.length(), (char * )gainCom.c_str())) // set the gain (0-255)
    {
        return SET_ERROR;
    } 

    currentGain = gain;

    return SUCCESSFUL;
}

AOTF_Controller::Error AOTF_Controller::setScanningFreq(float _startFreq, float _endFreq, int numOfFrames)
{
    float FreqRange = (_endFreq - _startFreq); //calculate range 

    //calculate DeltaFrequency (frequency increase after each captured frame)
    deltaFreq = (long) ((FreqRange/(float)(numOfFrames-1))*(float)CONVERSION_MHZ_TO_HZ); //conversion from MHz to Hz

    startFreq = (long) (_startFreq*CONVERSION_MHZ_TO_HZ);
    endFreq = (long) (_endFreq*CONVERSION_MHZ_TO_HZ);

    setFreq(_startFreq);

    return SUCCESSFUL;
}

AOTF_Controller::Error AOTF_Controller::increaseFreq()
{
    if (deltaFreq ==0)
    {
        return SET_ERROR;
    }

    long newFreq = currentFreq + deltaFreq;

    std::ostringstream oss;
    oss << "dds f 0 !" << std::fixed << std::setprecision(0) << newFreq << "\r";
    std::string freqCom = oss.str();

    //send command to the AOTF
    if(!AotfWrite(hAotfController, freqCom.length(), (char *)freqCom.c_str())) // set the frequency (80-120)value 
    {
        return SET_ERROR;
    }

    currentFreq = newFreq;
    return SUCCESSFUL;
}
```